# Mat's convertTo function complains assert error while converting the type of grayscale image to CV_32F in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I am a new recruit to OpenCV.And I just got an error that I can't understand why it occurred and don't know how to resolve it.

There is my code.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  Mat I = imread("water.jpg", 0);
  Mat W = imread("laosiji.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
  cout << I.channels() << endl;
  Mat CI(I.rows,I.cols,CV_32FC);
  I.convertTo(CI, CV_32FC);
  Mat FI;
  Mat IFI;

  dft(CI,FI,DFT_COMPLEX_OUTPUT | DFT_SCALE);
  idft(FI,IFI);
  imshow("water.jpg after idft transformation",IFI);

  return 0;
}
```

while I was running the program, it gave me an error:

```shell
    OpenCV Error: Bad number of channels (Source image must have 1, 3 or 4 channels) in cvConvertImage, file /var/tmp/portage/media-libs/opencv-3.1.0-r7/work/opencv-3.1.0/modules/imgcodecs/src/utils.cpp, line 611
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  /var/tmp/portage/media-libs/opencv-3.1.0-r7/work/opencv-3.1.0/modules/imgcodecs/src/utils.cpp:611: error: (-15) Source image must have 1, 3 or 4 channels in function cvConvertImage
```

However, from the code above, the channels outputted by the program is 1.It's hard for me to fiddle with this problem as I am not very familiar with OpenCV, can any veteran come out and explain it for me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you use `0` in one call to `imread`, and `CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE` in the other? (since `CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE == 0`)

Comment: Furthermore, I'm not sure how this even compiles, since the [`CV_32FC`](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/3.1.0/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/cvdef.h#L413) macro takes a parameter (number of channels). This could easily be the culprit, implicitly giving it some odd number of channels. I guess you don't treat warnings as errors, do you? :)
| Since those are 1 channel images anyway, why not `CV_32FC1`? Finally, the initialization in `Mat CI(I.rows,I.cols,CV_32FC);` is redundant -- just leave it default initialized, `convertTo` will do the right thing for you.

Comment: One more -- did you use a debugger? Or did you just assume that the exception is coming from that one visible call to `convertTo`? Because based on my test here it's not, it's the `imshow` that throws it, due to being given the 2 channel `IFI` matrix (you're getting a complex result by default).

Comment: Thanks for your patience to answer my question. The last advice you gave had solved my problem.You're The problem is not from the visible call to `convertTo` but from the `imshow` function. The `idft ` function will return a complex output matrix with 2 channels by default, and the `imshow` call the convertTo function implicitly. So this error popped up.

Comment: Can you spend little more time to collate your answer, making it more detailed and clear? Then, put it below as an answer and  I will receive it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer would be written by @Dan Mašek.But he may be so busy that I have waited for several days and there is not any response.As a result, I have to answer it by myself.
   First, the crux of the error is not the explicit call of `convertTo()` function.Otherwise, it is caused by the implicit call of it in `imshow()` function. From the code of mine, I invocate `imshow()` after `idft()`. But the `idft()` returns a matrix with 2 channels. And the implicit invocation of `convertTo` need a matrix with 1, 3 or 5 channels as arguments.So the error was spatted up.